# How to dynamic change styles with css and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I have a button that I need to change some styles when it's clicked. I probabely could do this easily with some class add and remove, but I change the first element when the page run, so now I need to remove the styles from the first and apply it on the clicked button, but I actually didn't get how could I make it cause of the nth-child(1). Someone could help?

Here's my html:

```
<tr>
<!-- ko foreach: optionValues -->
<td>
    <input type="radio" id="volt" name="volt"
        data-bind="attr: {id: 'CC-prodDetails-' + $data.value}, value: $parent.selectedOption">
    <button data-bind="attr: {for: 'CC-prodDetails-' + $data.value}, text:key, 
                                                click:function(key){
                                                    $parent.selectedOption(key);
                                                    $parent.selectedOptionValue(key);
                                                }" class="voltagem"></button>
</td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And that's my css:

```
input {
  display: none;
}

.voltagem {
  font-size: 20px;
  border-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: dotted;
  margin-left: 25px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 135px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.voltagem:focus {
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  outline: none;
}

td:nth-child(1) .voltagem {
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`css`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding for this. Set the class `voltagem` to the button if `$parent.selectedOption() === key`

```js
const model = function() {
  const self = this;
  const options = [ { key: "one" }, { key: "two" }, { key: "three" }];
  self.optionValues = ko.observable(options);
  self.selectedOption = ko.observable(options[0].key);
}

ko.applyBindings(new model)
```

```css
.voltagem {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: optionValues -->
    <td>
      <button data-bind="text: key, 
                         click: function(obj) { $parent.selectedOption(obj.key) },
                         css: { voltagem: $parent.selectedOption() == key }">
      </button>
    </td>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: You need to change the `click` binding function to

```
function(obj) {
  $parent.selectedOption(obj.key)
  $parent.selectedOptionValue(obj.key)
}
```

Comment: I tried this but isn't working on my project. I get "Error You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"

Comment: @MateusFernando something else is wrong. This works fine in the snippet.

Comment: Maybe some js/jquery only solution could help me better with this, bcause I can't change the ko code...